# javascript <script> appearing in the wrong place

Tags: javascript, html, css, dreamweaver

I have a .js animation that keeps appearing right at the end of the page although it's placed in the middle zone. I've tried with different places but with no change.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="sketch.js"></script>
```

You can see over here http://www.vtxfactory.org/ I have a circle that checks the amplitude of the audio playing:

```
    var song, analyzer;

    function preload() {

  song = loadSound('sounds/masterflash.mp3');
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(710, 200);
  song.loop();

  // create a new Amplitude analyzer
  analyzer = new p5.Amplitude();

  // Patch the input to an volume analyzer
  analyzer.setInput(song);
}

function draw() {
  background(255);

  // Get the average (root mean square) amplitude
  var rms = analyzer.getLevel();
  fill(127);
  stroke(0);

  // Draw an ellipse with size based on volume
  ellipse(width/2, height/2, 10+rms*200, 10+rms*200);
}
```

How can I force it into a fixed position?

Thanks,
Rui

Comment: Please provide more information along with the animation code. Your question above is very ambiguous and not understandable without you providing code where you are facing issue.

Comment: Updated my post!

Comment: You can simply add a style `position: fixed; bottom: 0px; right: 0px;`. Is this what you need?

Comment: Sadly it didn't work, you can see how I've set it up on line 469 of vtxfactory.org index.

Comment: Try adding `canvas { position: fixed; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; }` to your stylesheet. That should take care of it.

Comment: In the code, it's in the middle of my <body> but it appears below my footer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143340/discussion-between-shekhar-chikara-and-rui-farinha).

Comment: It worked man, you're genius, thanks!

Comment: Posting as an answer then... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution to get your `canvas` element position fixed to the bottom-right corner of the screen. Just add the following style to your stylesheet-

```
canvas { 
    position: fixed; 
    bottom: 0px; 
    right: 0px; 
}
```